# How to draw line graphs in Swift?

Tags: swift

For a new app I need to draw a line graph. That graph needs to consist of two references lines, and one line based on measurements per day (min 14 days, max 32 days). Up to the current date, that line based on measurements needs to be solid. From the current date up to the max, it needs to be dashed. For now, the data is in arrays.

I tried to find examples and also saw a framework called Core Plot. I do like the design of the Health graphs a lot. Maybe that is also possible with Core Plot.

Instead of figuring out the details myself, I was hoping I could find somebody (with experience with Core Plot) to setup an example app. So I have more of a head start developing my own app. Willing to pay for the effort, though.

Hope Stackoverflow is the right place for such a question.

Thanks.
Jan

Comment: Core Plot includes several example apps. The *Plot Gallery* is most comprehensive. On the "release-2.0" branch, the DatePlot and iPhone CPTTestApp have been converted to Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack overflow is most definitely not the right site for "please do all my work for me" questions. If you look at the Core-Plot project on Github it includes an example application, and a wiki with sample plots

It looks like the DropPlot Example App (from the samples wiki) is an example of a line plot. I suggest you start from that.

Here's what it's graph looks like[image]

Comment: It took me less than 5 seconds to find that info. You should do some searching before posting a question.